# What files are required inside .zip file when we deploy a NestJS app with Serverless Framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, nestjs, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

i have a [NestJS project integrated with Serverless Framework](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/serverless), when i run

```
$ serverless deploy
```

I realize that the .zip file inside **/.sererless** directory contains all the protect, it's necessary to have all the project inside the .zip file or can i remove the /src, /test ... directories? 
I can include or exclude files [like the documentation said](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging/) but
**what files are required when we deploy a NestJS app with Serverless Framework ?**

Answer (score 0):

Try using sls-next/serverless-component plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sls-next/serverless-component?activeTab=versions. It will do it out of the box.

Comment: While this package might solve the OP’s problem, it doesn’t answer their primary question as asked, which is what files are required within the zip file. Can you address that?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).